# mac open vim under tmux will casue vim Huaping

Tags: macos, crash, macvim, tmux

**Computer**：Mabbook Pro retina 2012 late

**OS**: OS X 10.9 and 10.10 all have this problem

**terminal**: iTerm and terminal all have this problem

**vim version**: Macvim 7.4.258

**tmux version**: stable 1.9a (bottled) HEAD

**my dotfiles**: [.vimrc .zshrc .tmux.conf](https://github.com/bobstar6/dotfile)

when I open vim in terminal, everything is ok. But when I open vim in tmux, I met this problem in the following picture.[look at screenshot](https://ruby-china.org/topics/22790)

Once in a time the problem disappear, but after I "brew update" and "brew upgrade" It comes back. I really don't known what's wrong with them.

I can't code without tmux + vim , who can help me.

I have tried clear .tmux.conf, the problem still there. I tried to update the vim bundles, the problem still there.

Comment: I'm sorry your question isn't clear.  Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: First I open tmux, then I open vim in tmux, the vim display code abnormal. You can see the last picture of this page https://ruby-china.org/topics/22790

Comment: I have resolved the problem by reinstall OS X Yosemite.